# can't use jQuery code after grabbing it by php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I used jQuery ajax to grab jQuery scripts and javascript codes and put it in the head:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#SignUpBtn").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
           url: "ajax/signupfrm.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: "do=getScript",
           success: function(data){
               $("head").append(data);
           }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The JavaScript works but not the jQuery.

Here is the jQuery code grabbed from the PHP File:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#username').change(function(){
           var unameVal = $('#username').val();
           $.ajax({
               url: 'ajax/unameCheck.php',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {'do':'submit','uname':unameVal},
               beforeSend: function() {
                   $('#unameCheck').html('<img src='img/giphy.gif'/>').slideDown(500);
               },
               success: function(data){
                   if(data == '0'){
                     $('#unameCheck').css({'background-color':'#FFBAA4','color':'#f00','border':'1px solid #f00'});
                     $('#unameCheck').html(unameVal + ' is already exist');
                   }else if(data == '1'){
                     $('#unameCheck').css({'background-color':'#AAFFAA','color':'#00B600','border':'1px solid #0f0'});
                     $('#unameCheck').html(unameVal + ' is available');
                   }else{
                     $('#unameCheck').slideUp(500);
                   }
               }
           })
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you're loading scripts you'll want to use use [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: can u show me how please ? or just give me a documentation thank u :)

Comment: Oh thanks i don't see it first time :)

Comment: it's dosen't works for me please help me !

Comment: If it doesn't work for you post another question showing what you have tried and what errors you are having.

Comment: Jay meant put together some code attempting to use $.getScript() and ask a question on it not post the same question again under a new account

Comment: @developerwjk but it wasn't new, it was at least 1 minute old ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript code contains a syntax error on this line:

```js
$('#unameCheck').html('<img src='img/giphy.gif'/>').slideDown(500);
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're trying to use single quotes inside a single-quoted string. This is interpreted as terminating the string; use double quotes instead for either the inner or the outer string (but not both).